# my tooltip in d3 won't show up in the right place

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, tooltip, scatter-plot

I trying to add a simple tooltip to my scatterplot, the thing is that it shows below the graph, I don't know if it is for the "div", but I've tried with svg and g and still won't show.
Is there any other way I can add my tooltip?

```
const tooltip = d3.select("#CraftBeer")
                  .append("div")
                  .style("opacity", 0)
                  .attr("class", "tooltip")
                  .style("background-color", "white")
                  .style("border", "solid")
                  .style("border-width", "1px")
                  .style("border-radius", "5px")
                  .style("padding", "10px")


              const mouseover = function(d) {
                tooltip
                  .style("opacity", 1)
              }

              const mousemove = function(d) {
                tooltip
                  .html(d.beer + "<br/>" + "ABV:" + d.abv + "%" + "<br/>" + "IBU:" + d.ibu +"<br/>" + "SRM:" + d.srm)
                  .style("left", (d3.event.pageX+10)+"px") // It is important to put the +90: other wise the tooltip is exactly where the point is an it creates a weird effect
                  .style("top", (d3.event.pageY-10)+"px")
              }


              const mouseleave = function(d) {
                tooltip
                  .transition()
                  .duration(300)
                  .style("opacity", 0)
              }



    plot = g.selectAll("bottle")
                .data(data)
                .enter()
                .append("g")
                    .attr("transform", d => `translate(${xScale(d.abv)},${yScale(d.ibu)})`)
                    .style("fill", d => colors(d.srm))
                    .style("stroke", d => colors(d.srm))
                    .style("stroke-width", "13px")


    plot.append("g")
            .attr("transform", `scale(0.150) translate(-256,-256)`) 
            .selectAll()
            .data(bottlePath)
            .enter()
            .append("path")
            .attr("d", d => d)

    plot.on("mouseover", mouseover)
        .on("mousemove", mousemove)
        .on("mouseleave", mouseleave)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the `style` for your tooltip before the `html` like

```
              const mousemove = function(d) {
                tooltip
                  .style("left", (d3.event.pageX+10)+"px") // It is important to put the +90: other wise the tooltip is exactly where the point is an it creates a weird effect
                  .style("top", (d3.event.pageY-10)+"px")
                  .html(d.beer + "<br/>" + "ABV:" + d.abv + "%" + "<br/>" + "IBU:" + d.ibu +"<br/>" + "SRM:" + d.srm)

              }
```